# getting and editing css class of an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

In JavaScript, the `className` property gives the class name of an HTML element, but how to get the contents of the class.

Comment: Please revisit your other questions and accept the best answers on each of them (i.e. click the big check mark to the left of the best answers). It'll give you a 2-point reputation bump per question, and it helps others know what helped you, thus improving the overall quality of information on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to get the cssRules array but since it is not cross platform you should use a code like this:

```
if ( document.styleSheets[0].cssRules ) {
    var cssRules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
} else if ( document.styleSheets[0].rules ) {
    var cssRules = document.styleSheets[0].rules;
}
```

now cssRules is an array of selectors in your stylesheet you can go through it like this:

```
for( var i = 0; i < cssRules.length; ++i ) {
     if( cssRules[i].selectorText == '.myClass' ) {
         alert( cssRules[i].style.color );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual style rules are stored in the [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style).

Also, [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) has some really nice methods for working with style. If you want to explore that route, check out the [`css` method](http://api.jquery.com/css).

**EDIT:** *Just re-read the question and realized that the OP was asking about the style rules for the class, not the style rules for the element. However, because the context isn't exactly clear, I'll let this answer stand for now, as it may still be helpful.*

Comment: The `style` property is the pure JavaScript way. You'll want to look at that then.

Comment: Well, jQuery is written in pure JavaScript, but it's a framework, and the benefits you get from it come at the cost of some overhead. I can see the OP's point.

Comment: Honestly since when is 31k overhead? The time saved on development makes up for a lot of other factors.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I know, I feel the same way about 31K worth of overhead. In most applications, it truly doesn't make a difference in performance.